# No tab preview on Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have Blu studio 5.0 on Android 4.1. When I open the tab viewer in Chrome, all I get is a list of open tabs and no preview of them. Does anyone know why?

I have this problem on the beta and regular version.

[image: simple list of open tabs]

Answer (score 1):

You've (accidentally) enabled **Accessibility Tab Switcher**.

From [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/19/quick-tip-experimental-accessibility-tab-switcher-in-chrome-beta-makes-tab-switching-compact-pressure-free/),

> Chrome Beta for Android has an experimental "Accessibility Tab Switcher" flag that'll allow you to switch tabs in a compact, pleasing interface, also enabling you to bring back closed tabs with a handy "undo" button.

You can find the setting on `chrome://flags/#enable-accessibility-tab-switcher`

Comment: I just tried on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, Chrome 50, but it didn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 1):

An update to Andrew's answer that worked for me: the accessibility tab switcher is not an experimental feature anymore, you can find it under "Configuration>Accessibility", as "simplified view for open tabs".

Answer (score -1):

Try going into settings -> Application Manager -> Chrome -> Force Stop -> Clear data (Warning this will clear your saved passwords so take a note of them!) -> Clear cache. I hope this works for you it did for me. If this doesn't work try installing another browser such as firefox.